# Why is a function passed through props into a child component behaving differently on a key press vs. button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React project where the parent component (functional) holds state to determine what formatting is applied to a list. When the user clicks a button, a modal is generated - I pass an anonymous function to that modal as props (`onMainButtonClick`), which when called flips the state and changes the formatting of the list (logic for this is in parent component).

When I use the button in my modal component (`onClick={() => onMainButtonClick()}`), the code works as expected. However, I would also like an enter press to trigger this. Therefore I have the following code implemented for this, but it doesn't function as expected. The modal closes and the function fires (I know this as I put a console log in there...) but the state that impacts the formatting is not changed.

EDIT: Having made a proposed change below (to memo'ize the onEnterPress function so it gets removed properly), here's the full code for the modal:

```
import { React, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Modal = ({
  title,
  description,
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  onMainButtonClick,
  mainButtonText,
  secondaryButtonText,
  closeOnly,
}) => {
  const node = useRef();

  const onEnterPress = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
        onMainButtonClick();
      }
    },
    [onMainButtonClick]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onEnterPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", onEnterPress);
    };
  }, [onMainButtonClick]);

  const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
    if (node.current.contains(e.target)) {
      return null;
    }
    onClose();
  };

  if (!isOpen) return null;
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
{// JSX here, removed for brevity},
    document.body
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

And the code for the parent (which shows the modal and passes down onMainButtonClick):

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { decode } from "html-entities";
import useList from "../../queries/useList";
import useBuyItem from "../../mutations/useBuyItem";
import Header from "../Shared/Header";
import Description from "../Shared/Description";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";
import BuyOverlay from "./BuyOverlay";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import ViewOperations from "./ViewOperations";

const View = (props) => {
  const [buyOverlayOpen, setBuyOverlayOpen] = useState(false);
  const [viewBuyersOverlayOpen, setBuyersOverlayOpen] = useState(false);
  const [viewBuyers, setViewBuyers] = useState(false);
  const [buyItemId, setBuyItemId] = useState();

  const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useList(props.match.params.id);
  const buyItemMutation = useBuyItem(buyItemId, props.match.params.id, () =>
    setBuyOverlayOpen(false)
  );

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading the list...</div>;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <div>An error occured, please refresh and try again</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="mb-10 text-gray-600 font-light">
        <Header text={data.name} />
        <Description text={data.description} />
        <ViewOperations
          toggleViewBuyers={() => setViewBuyers(!viewBuyers)}
          toggleBuyersOverlay={() =>
            setBuyersOverlayOpen(!viewBuyersOverlayOpen)
          }
          viewBuyers={viewBuyers}
        />
        <div id="list" className="container mt-10">
          {data.items.length === 0
            ? "No items have been added to this list"
            : ""}
          <ul className="flex flex-col w-full text-white md:text-xl">
            {data.items.map((item) => {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  item={decode(item.item)}
                  description={decode(item.description)}
                  itemId={item._id}
                  isBought={decode(item.bought)}
                  boughtBy={decode(item.boughtBy)}
                  boughtDate={decode(item.boughtDate)}
                  viewlink={item.link}
                  handleBuy={() => {
                    setBuyItemId(item._id);
                    setBuyOverlayOpen(true);
                  }}
                  key={item._id}
                  viewBuyers={viewBuyers}
                />
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <BuyOverlay
        isOpen={buyOverlayOpen}
        message="Message"
        onClose={() => setBuyOverlayOpen(false)}
        onConfirmClick={(buyerName) => {
          buyItemMutation.mutate(buyerName);
        }}
      />
      <Modal
        title="Title"
        description="Description"
        isOpen={viewBuyersOverlayOpen}
        onClose={() => {
          setBuyersOverlayOpen(false);
        }}
        onMainButtonClick={() => {
          setViewBuyers(true);
          setBuyersOverlayOpen(false);
        }}
        mainButtonText="OK"
        secondaryButtonText="Cancel"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default View;
```

Any ideas for why this is happening? I have a feeling it might be something to do with useEffect here, but I'm a bit lost otherwise...

Comment: First of all you have an undeclared dependency on the effect, which is `onMainButtonClick`, which may part of the problem, but that depends on surrounding code that you didn’t provide. Can you extend the question and provide a little more detail?

Comment: So you want to listen to enter for everything on the page?

Comment: Yep, when the modal is open I want to listen to enter on the page. @PierPaoloRamon I'll try and give some more detail now above

Answer (score 0):

`onEnterPress` is most probably directly defined in your functional component and that's why its reference changes every time your component re-renders. Your `useEffect` closes over this newly defined function on each render so your handler is not going to work as you expected.
You can wrap your `onEnterPress` with `useCallback` to memoize your handler `onEnterPress` so its definition stays the same throughout each render just like this:

```
const onEnterPress = useCallback(e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      onMainButtonClick();
    }
  }, [onMainButtonClick]); // Another function dep. You can also wrap it with useCallback or carry over its logic into the callback here
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', onEnterPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', onEnterPress);
    };
  }, [onEnterPress]);
```

Comment: This makes sense - and sounds like a good tweak to make based on the fact that onEnterPress is, as you described, defined inside the functional component. However, I've made the changes and still getting the same issue. Will try and post a bit more detail above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out in the end - turns out it was as simple as my enterPress callback needing a preventDefault statement before the if block (`e.preventDefault()`).

There must have been something else on the page that was capturing the enter press and causing it to behave strangely.